# Is there any "List.divideAt" HOF in the F# library?

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming

I implemented a function that I chose to call `divideAt`:

```
module List =
    let divideAt predicate list =
        let rec divideAt' acc = function
            | [] -> (List.rev acc, [])
            | h::_ as ls when predicate h -> (List.rev acc, ls)
            | h::t -> divideAt' (h::acc) t
        divideAt' [] list
```

The idea is relatively simple: sometimes you want to, given an element in a list, separate all the elements before it into a left list and all the elements after it into another.

I looked all over List's functions and I couldn't find anything that would allow me to do this in a performant way. Or is there? An equivalent, albeit slower implementation relying entirely in high order functions can be accomplished in this way, for instance:

```
let divideAt predicate list =
    match List.tryFindIndex predicate list with
    | None -> (list, [])
    | Some(index) -> (List.take index list, List.skip index list)
```

Is there something that would allow me to implement this even more succinctly without having to rely on the "low level" recursion algorithm yet without having a performance penalty as I have when using this HOF implementation?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the only change I can think about is using `List.splitAt` which already handles, the take/skip part (probably better) :

```
let divideAt predicate list =
  match List.tryFindIndex predicate list with
    None       -> list, []
  | Some index -> List.splitAt index list
```

Alternatively here is another syntax for the same thing ; I don't think there should be a performance difference between function call and match expression but in case :

```
let divideAt predicate list =
  List.tryFindIndex predicate list
  |> Option.map (List.splitAt >> (|>) list)
  |> defaultArg <| (list, [])
```

Comment: Which version of F# has `List.splitAt` in List module?

Comment: @Petr They were added in [F# 4.0](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharpLangDesign/blob/master/FSharp-4.0/ListSeqArrayAdditions.md)

Comment: Hm, seems MSDN docs are quite behind: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353738.aspx VisualStudio 2015 with F# has this function though. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, "splitAt". I was sure I had seen that function before, I just couldn't remember its name. It's unfortunate that you have to actually do 2 passes on the list but you can't have the cake ant eat it too.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done very efficiently with `List.partition`:

```
let divideAt predicate ll =
    let split = ref false
    let splitter predicate x =
        split := !split || (predicate x); !split

    ll |> List.partition (splitter predicate)
```

and using it like in example below:

```
> divideAt ((=) 7) [1; 8; 2; 7; 3; 6]
val it : int list * int list = ([7; 3; 6], [1; 8; 2])
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want `split := !split || (predicate x)` so the predicate isn't run on elements past the split-point?

Comment: @ildjarn: Thanks, good point, reversing operand order adds to single element pass efficiency.

Comment: Well, this surely looks ugly :( But +1 for effort.

Comment: @devouredelysium: You might be surprised to hear that in F# library implementation the same "ugly" pattern is used quite frequently; 29 times just implementing `Seq` module functions. Using `ref` for efficiency is OK and safe as long as statefulness and side effects are carefully sealed within outer pure function.

Comment: "Using ref for efficiency is OK and safe as long as statefulness and side effects are carefully sealed within outer pure function." -> well, it's just uglier without any clear benefit. It's equally fast as my initial recursive implementation and a (arguably) uglier. Not attempting to enter into a flame war, but it isn't as the F# compiler / library is the prettiest open source project alive.

Comment: In fact, partition will require a full sweep over the list, while my approach only needs to go until the first element where "predicate" is true.

Comment: @devouredelysium: And `(List.take index list, List.skip index list)` in your approach do not require any list traversing in addition to `List.tryFindIndex` one, right?

Comment: Gene, as previously stated, I don't want to enter into a heated argument regarding this. As patently stated above, I was comparing your mutable implementation to my recursive implementation. As you can probably atest in my OP, I explicitly stated that my HOF implementation (2nd algorithm) is slower than the first, and that was precisely the reason of me starting this post..